# Shell Script - Collapsing numbers

Tags: bash, unix, awk, numbers, sh

I am trying to collapse numbers so that they are more readable. So far i have a dataset like this: 1,2,3,4
I am trying to collapse them into: 1-4.

However when I have a dataset like "1,2,4,5,6" (with missing numbers), I cannot collapse them into 1,2,4-6.

for a data set without any missing numbers it can be easily done with this:

DATA="1,2,3,4"

echo $DATA | awk -F"," '{print $1"-"$NF}'

I have created a script that can collapse the numbers however there are several issues with it. I feel like it is a losing battle as the script is over 120 lines long and I have definitely overcomplicated it.

Happy for any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Provide the input, expected output for various cases, your script, and a specific error or question

Comment: Question needs sample file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code demonstrates one way to do what you want:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

data='1,2,4,5,6'

IFS=, read -r -a numbers <<<"$data"

range_start=
range_end=
sep=
for num in "${numbers[@]}" _; do
    if [[ -z $range_start ]]; then
        range_start=$num
        range_end=$num
    elif [[ $num != _ && num -eq range_end+1 ]]; then
        range_end=$num
    else
        if (( range_end == range_start )); then
            printf '%s%s' "$sep" "$range_start"
        elif (( range_end == (range_start+1) )); then
            printf '%s%s,%s' "$sep" "$range_start" "$range_end"
        else
            printf '%s%s-%s' "$sep" "$range_start" "$range_end"
        fi
        sep=,
        range_start=$num
        range_end=$num
    fi
done
printf '\n'
```

The output is:

```
1,2,4-6
```

Comment: Wow, that is perfect, I cant thank you enough for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip lines with missing numbers (and the sequence is monotonic increasing) do this

```
echo $DATA | awk -F"," '$NF == NF {print $1"-"$NF}'
```